# how to get the non duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to make a request in SQL.

I have a field that contains IDs. 
These IDs are written in 2 ways and are prefixed either by'C0' or by'E0' for example: "C0121213" or "E0121213".

I would like to make a query allowing me to find the number of IDs starting with C0 but not duplicating starting with E0.

That is, I would like to find IDs that do not have C0 or E0 pairs.

Thank you in advance

I started with a request :

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     SBYN
WHERE    ID IN (
                SELECT LID
                FROM   SBYN
                WHERE LEFT(ID,2) = 'C0'
                OR LEFT(ID, 2) = 'E0'
                GROUP BY LID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                )
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: what's your question? you have error?   show error message .. wrong result  ? .. show a proper data sample you actual result and your expected  result

Answer (score 2):

`NOT EXISTS` comes to mind:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM SBYN s
WHERE s.ID LIKE 'C0%' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SBYN s2
                  WHERE s2.ID LIKE 'E0%' AND
                        SUBSTRING(s2.ID, 2) = SUBSTRING(s.ID, 2)
                 );
```

If you want the `ID`s, then use `SELECT ID` rather than `SELECT COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    ID
FROM SBYN s1
WHERE
    ID LIKE 'C0%' AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SBYN s2
                WHERE s2.ID LIKE 'E0' AND
                      SUBSTRING(s1.ID, 3) = SUBSTRING(s2.ID, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from sbyn s
where not exists (
  select 1 from sbyn
  where left(id, 2) <> left(s.id, 2) and
  right(id, 3, length(id)) = right(s.id, 3, length(s.id))
)
```

This will return all the non duplicates.
If you care only about those starting with `C0` add to the where clause:

```
and left(s.id) = 'C0'
```